# Alliteration Request: A word that starts with C and means “remarkable”

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, alliteration

I am writing a YEAR 12 English assignment which is a feature article about the novel *Girl With A Pearl Earring*. I am working on my conclusion when I noticed I had a chance to add in some more alliteration; however, I am stumped trying to find a good word starting with **C** to replace 'remarkable' (the sentence is below). I have been looking for over an hour in both a thesaurus and online and most of the words I have come across do not start with the letter C or just don't fit.

I would be really grateful if you could give me some suggestions.

> “From luxurious language to **remarkable** characters ...”

Comment: Have you had some fun with a thesaurus?

Comment: . *Charismatic.*

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately there are are none i can find that actually fit. :/

Comment: @aparente001, i dont think that one will fit because from my understanding (and google) charismatic is someone with charming personality or traits that are attractive and alluring to others. Not all of the characters are "charming" :P

Comment: @Caitlynisdunwithyou: Do you want to replace 'remarkable' as in 'extraordinary' or as in 'very odd'  ? If it's the latter, curious would be a good replacement. If you mean it as 'important / prominent', Conspicuous works.

Comment: @Bhoomika Arora: As in 'extraordinary'.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. And questions lacking evidence of reasonable research are not appropriate.

Comment: incomparable, cool, uncommon, incredible, unconventional, eye-catching, crazy.  // Yes, Edwin is right.  Please describe your efforts so far, in your answer, as you did here the comment.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: What do you mean? How can i possibly show research? i am just asking for a word and i wouldn't be asking if i had already found something on google or in a thesauras after spending the last hour looking.

Comment: Quirky, kooky, kinky, accurately drawn, scrumptious, screwball.

Comment: Yeah try using "Kinky" in a year 12 english assignment :D

Comment: Well, now, you see, that's another bit of information you should add to your question so it fits better with the requirements of the site.

Comment: Carefully drawn, captivating, crisply drawn.

Comment: @aparente001: i said it was for an English assignment

Comment: So you did.  Okay, all you have to add, when you edit your question, is that you tried a thesaurus and nothing was working.  // I don't think alliteration is very effective when it's forced.  I like it best when it's pure serendipity.

Comment: "*carefully crafted characters*" would give you 3 at the price of 2.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: that is actually really good!! thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“From luxurious language to **compelling** characters ...”

Answer (score 2):

**[Conspicuous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/conspicuous)**

> `1.` Standing out so as to be clearly visible.
>
> *‘he was very thin, with a conspicuous Adam's apple’*
>
> `1.1.` Attracting notice or attention.
>
> *‘he showed conspicuous bravery’*

---

Tossing around adjectives between sentences seems to make no `*remarkable*` difference:

> *'from luxurious language to **conspicuous** characters'*
>
> *‘he showed **remarkable** bravery’*

Answer (score 1):

Captivating.

> ˈkaptəˌvādiNG/
>   adjective
>   capable of attracting and holding interest; charming.